# Icon on a white background

Tags: java, android

Why icons in Android 7 are on white background? Something like this:

[image]

How can I delete this "white background"?

Comment: "Why icons in on Android 7 are on white background ?" -- they aren't. That is something particular to your device, your home screen, or possibly your project.

Comment: Please back up and tell us the problem you are trying to solve.  If you are looking for recommendations on image editors, this is not the right forum.

Comment: its have only one solution, design icon on the shape of icon with white background. its a device depended problem.

Comment: when i build this same app on android 5, icon look fine, only problem with api 24, it is not problem with graphic, it's something wrong with new android studio, Recently appeared something like ic_launcher_round

Comment: check my new sceeenshot, 1 app look fine, but my testapp is with this 'white"

Comment: If your project's manifest has `android:roundIcon` attributes anywhere, get rid of them, and see if that helps.

Comment: still this same ;/ There must be some way, because some applications do not have this white background